# Problem copying HTML from JEditorPane to external applications

Tags: java, swing, openoffice.org, mozilla, jeditorpane

I'm having trouble copying HTML from JEditorPane to system clipboard and then pasting into other applications:

- OpenOffice 3.2 - Says "Requested clipboard format isn't available"
- Thunderbird 3.13 - Does nothing on paste
- Firefox 3.6.9 - Accepts plain text but for example in GMail "Compose mail" does nothing on paste

I'm running WinXP by the way. In other applications like text-editors, MS Outlook, MS Word etc. it works as expected, ie I get plain text with HTML tags stripped or formatted text according to which mimetype the application wants.

Anyone has an idea what's wrong? Is it a problem in Swing or in OpenOffice/Mozilla?

See test application below and try out. I've also tried with a custom *Transferable* but as soon as I provide a *DataFlavor* with mimetype="text/html" it stops to work in applications mentioned above.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Demonstrates problem with copy/paste between JEditorPane and OpenOffice/Thunderbird/Firefox.
 * 
 * @author martin
 */
public class HtmlCopyDemo extends JFrame
{
    public HtmlCopyDemo()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(400, 400);

        final JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
        editor.setContentType("text/html");
        editor.setText("<html><head></head><body>Here's some <b>formatted</b> <i>text</i></body></html>");
        add(editor, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton button = new JButton("Copy");
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                editor.selectAll();
                editor.copy();
            }
        });

        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"text/html", "text/plain"});
        panel.add(combo);
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = editor.getText();
                editor.setContentType((String) combo.getSelectedItem());
                editor.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new HtmlCopyDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a problem on the receiver end. (I can't be 100% sure since I don't have your environment.)

Add `Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();` to your button's `actionPerformed` and I can see the clipboard has the right stuff with full html:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    Here's some <b>formatted</b> <i>text</i>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pasting into Word 2007 works correctly.

Comment: Yes it works fine in all applications I tested besides OOo/Mozilla. I found this bug report at Bugzilla which probably is the cause: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=395218